# defining unique field in solr

Tags: solr

I have a document in solr as

```
<entity name="Category" dataSource="ds1" pk="CategoryId"
    query="SELECT CategoryId, Description, ImageUrl FROM Category">
    <field column="CategoryId" name="CategoryId" />
    <entity name="PackCategory" pk="PackId, CategoryId"
     query="SELECT PackId FROM PackCategory WHERE CategoryId = ${Category.CategoryId}" >
     <entity name="Pack" pk="PackId"
      query="SELECT PackId, IsActive FROM Pack WHERE PackId = ${PackCategory.PackId}" >
      <field column="IsActive" name="IsActive" />
      <entity name="PartnerPackTrans" pk="PackId, PartnerId" transformer="TemplateTransformer">
       query="SELECT PartnerId FROM PartnerPackTrans WHERE PackId = ${Pack.PackId}" >
           <field column="PartnerId" name="PartnerId" />
      </entity>
</entity>
     </entity>
    </entity>
   </entity>
```

My unique id is a combination of (Cateogry.CategoryId, Pack.PackId, PartnerPackTrans.PartnerId). How can I define this is solr in schema.xml in unique field

Update
After going through various post I added this my solr-config file

```
 <updateRequestProcessorChain name="id">
  <processor class="solr.CloneFieldUpdateProcessorFactory">
    <str name="source">CategoryId</str>
    <str name="source">PartnerId</str>
    <str name="dest">id</str>
  </processor>
  <processor class="solr.ConcatFieldUpdateProcessorFactory">
    <str name="fieldName">id</str>
    <str name="delimiter">-</str>
  </processor>
  <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory" />
  <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />
</updateRequestProcessorChain>
```

But I get this error in solr
Document is missing mandatory uniqueKey field: id

i am refering this post 
[Solr Composite Unique key from existing fields in schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17806821/solr-composite-unique-key-from-existing-fields-in-schema)

I am using solr version 5.3

Answer (score 1):

In Solr, you can add a [unique key](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#The_Unique_Key_Field):

> The  declaration can be used to inform Solr that there is a field in your index which should be unique for all documents. If a document is added that contains the same value for this field as an existing document, the old document will be deleted.

So, in your case, if your field is called `unique`, you have to add:

```
<uniqueKey>unique</uniqueKey>
```

**UPDATE**

To answer to your comment, in your `schema.xml`, you can create a new field:

```xml
<field name="unique" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"  multiValued="true" />
```

After that, you can copy the fields that you want in your new field:

```xml
<copyField source="Cateogry.CategoryId" dest="unique"/>
<copyField source="Pack.PackId" dest="unique"/>
<copyField source="PartnerPackTrans.PartnerId" dest="unique"/>
```

Comment: how can I add a combination of columns in this? My columns are coming from different entities.

Comment: I tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17806821/solr-composite-unique-key-from-existing-fields-in-schema but it gives me error "your document do not have a unique field id, where to add id in the document

Comment: it's not recommended to use `text_general` as unique key type (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SOLR/UniqueKey)

Comment: tObi is right, you shouldn't use `text_general`, for the reasons he linked to in that link. However I couldn't figure out what type would be wise. The link says `It is strongly advised to use one of the un-analyzed types (e.g. string)`, but which type is for string? I finally found https://solr.apache.org/guide/6_6/field-types-included-with-solr.html#field-types-included-with-solr, which shows it as `StrField`, class `solr.StrField`. Hope that helps someone.