# Solr: create unique key with concatenation

Tags: xml, database, solr, unique-key

I need to create multiple unique key in solr collection, and readed related question [Solr Composite Unique key from existing fields in schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17806821/solr-composite-unique-key-from-existing-fields-in-schema) . But i need this key to be human-readable, now i see hash. I added to:

`solrconfig.xml`:

```
<config>
    <!-- Here is standart config -->
    ...
    <!-- My updateRequestProcessorChain  -->
    <updateRequestProcessorChain name="inn-unique-key">
        <processor class="solr.CloneFieldUpdateProcessorFactory">
            <str name="source">inn</str>
            <str name="source">source</str>
            <str name="source">kpp</str>
            <str name="dest">id</str>
        </processor>
        <processor class="solr.ConcatFieldUpdateProcessorFactory">
            <str name="fieldName">id</str>
            <str name="delimiter">-</str>
        </processor>
        <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />
    </updateRequestProcessorChain>
</config>
```

`schema.xml` - inside `<schema>` tag:

```
<requestHandler name="/update" class="solr.UpdateRequestHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="update.chain">inn-unique-key</str>
    </lst>
</requestHandler>
<field name="inn" type="long" required="true" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="kpp" type="long" default="0" required="false" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="source" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
```

When i try to add record, for example:

```
{
    "inn": 764575576,
    "kpp": 123,
    "source": "self"
}
```

I see a hash "6dab8c2b-e5e3-4d5a-a17a-759da05a3e64" in "id" field. Help me please, how to see "764575576-self-123" instead?

Answer (score 1):

I've found my error. `updateRequestProcessorChain` and `requestHandler` tags must be in solrconfig.xml both! Not in schema.xml